# How to center the menu

Tags: html, center

I am currently working with a webshop, and I have some trouble centering the top menu.

The code look like this:

```
 <div id="webshop-topmenu" class="row logoRow ProductMenu_TD">
     <div align="center">
         <div class="small-12 columns menus">
             <nav class="top-bar productmenu" data-topbar role="navigation">
                 <ul class="title-area">
                     <li class="name"></li>
                     <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
                 </ul>

                 <section class="top-bar-section">[[ProductMenu]]</section>
              </nav>

              <div class="sub-nav pagelinks TopMenu_TD hide-for-small">[[TopMenu]]</div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

No matter what code I use, the menu always aligns to the right, and I want to center it.

I have tried the `<div align"center">` and `<center>` and a couple of other codes, but nothing seems to work.

Hope you can help me here.

[What it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bltRu.png)

Comment: You should put some code (HTML + CSS) and that too in the question itself so that you may get better help out here.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should add tags in edit so it goes to right parts of the site :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<center> and "align"
```

are deprecated.

After getting a link to the page:
If you want to center the ul#ProductMenu_List, change your CSS:

```
.top-bar-section #ProductMenu_List {
     margin: 0 auto;
     //float: right;
     //margin-right: -10px;
}

.top-bar-section ul li {
    //float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

If you want to center your div.TopMenu_TD, do following in CSS:

```
.logoRow .menus .pagelinks {
    //float: right;
}
```

If you want to center elements, "float" is in most case the opposite of helpful. Text-align: center, display: inline-block and/or margin: 0 auto are in most case the solution.

And take your to google for Html5 and CSS3. You will need it.

**Update**
After seeing that you only have access to the templates - add following code to "Kodefelter" - Head:

```
<style>
    .top-bar-section #ProductMenu_List {
         margin: 0 auto;
         float: none;
         max-width: 400px;//or another value
         display: block;
    }

    #ProductMenu_List > li {
        float: none;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .logoRow .menus .pagelinks {
        float: none;
        display: block!important;
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 500px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Can you show me exactly how the code should look like? When i paste this code, is shows up as text :-)

Comment: You must change your css-files, not html files ;) app.min.css to be precise.

Comment: I can't access that css files, because the webshop is being made on a danish site called DanDomain. Is there anything else i can do then?? :-)

Comment: So, you have only access to the backend of the webshop? Or do you have access to the html or javascript files?

Comment: Yeah i think so. I have posted another picture in the first thread so you can see what i see ;-)

Comment: I updated my post. Also i have send an edit-request to your first post, where i formatted the code for better readability.

Comment: Tried to add the code where you said, and still nothing happens. Im so sorry for wasting your time :-(

Comment: No problem, this time it was my error. //float: none; means to comment out the existing code. But you cant access the existing (css-)code, so we added an inline style block. I updated my code, now it should work. Also i added a media query, to not harm the mobile design.

Comment: It makes no change still unfortunately. Maybe its just meant to not work :-( . But thanks for all your help Stefan. I really appretiate it!! :-)

Comment: I am not giving up yet. 
Seems like there is a problem, the style-block is empty. Propably something because of the media query? I removed the media query from the code, try that please. Use the code after "Update:"

Comment: Hi Stefan. Sorry for my late reply. I tried your new code, and something happend. The menu is now align to the left, so i think you are getting closer!
I posted how it looks in the first post under "newest picture".

Comment: Hi Benjamin, glad you are back :) Seems like we are talking about another site now? I would guess, somewhere in the code is still a float: left; or text-align: left; Or the #ProductMenu_List need a (max)width. But without a link it is hard to tell.

Comment: Hi Stefan. It is still the same site, just other pictures. The code is exactly the same as it was before ;-)

Comment: It's from this site: http://ved-ikke.webshop8.dk/shop/frontpage.html?BypassShopClosed=1

Comment: Well, a part of the top menu got centered now. This is really exciting! :D - If you check the link, you can see the "lower" part of the menu is centered now :D

Comment: I know that feeling ;) You forgot the display: block; in the first part.

Comment: I copied your code, and still only the "lower part" gets centered. Am i putting it in the wrong place? :-)

Comment: You still forgot the display: block; for #ProductMenu_List ;)

Comment: Im not sure what you mean Stefan. Sorry :D - I inserted the kode in the area " Kodefelter - Head " - Is there somewhere else i should put the code?

Comment: The code in my **update** section begins with **.top-bar-section #ProductMenu_List**. A part of that is **display: block;** and that´s missing in your code.

Comment: I have linked to a picture, so you can see what i have inserted. I feel like we are so close, and that i am just too stupid :D

Comment: Now the **display: block;** is there, but the comment **//or another value** is commenting it out. Remove the **//or another value**. Then it should work.

Comment: You're the man Stefan. It finally works! Am so happy now! Thank you thank you thank you!!!! :D :D :D :D

Comment: Glad i could help :) Now, if you would be so nice and mark my post as correct answer ;)

Comment: Hi Stefan. I hope you still follow the thread. The code worked, and the menu is center now.
Something happend though, because my menu is a "drop-down", and that is also being centered when i drop i down.

How do i make that look normal again? :-)

Really hope to hear from you! :-D

Comment: Well, it would have been too strange if everything was fine now :D Where is the drop-down, i don´t see one?

Comment: Haha you are absolutely right :-D - It's on this link http://benjaminmadsen.webshop8.dk/shop/frontpage.html - You can see it under "E-Væske" and "Eleaf" :-)

Comment: Morning. I updated my post. Just need to change a selector.